# What's wrong with the Create Private Channel JSON and/or Graph API via Power Automate?

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, mstest, power-automate, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm creating a flow to provision Teams with a certain structure, a template, but when I get to the point of creating the private channel there is no way to get it right. I'm always trying to do the same using the graph explorer but when I paste the json body in power automate all sort of errors are shown.

This is the code that works in the Graph Explorer

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group_id}/channels
Content-type: application/json

{ "membershipType": "Private",
  "displayName": "Confidential info",
  "members":[{    
           "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
           "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('<userID>')",
           "roles":["owner"]
            }]
}
```

and this the request body according to the documentation:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{group_id}/channels
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.Core.channel",
  "membershipType": "private",
  "displayName": "My First Private Channel",
  "description": "This is my first private channels",
  "members":
     [
        {
           "@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
           "user@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('{user_id}')",
           "roles":["owner"]
        }
     ]
}
```

I want to add this code to a flow but when I run it the following error message appears:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "channel cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: channel",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "<id>",
      "date": "<date>"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Hope it helps if anyone in the future faces the same issue.

"@odata.type" and "@odata.bind" have to be initialized as string variables otherwise the http request will result in error.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, to initialize as string variables? Can you give the specific, direct answer? Some things that are implied, are not obvious to every-one.